# Regular Expression - Replace carriage return line feed with a space

Tags: regex, replace, space, carriage-return, linefeed

I have a third party software package which allows me to provide regular expression validation on a form field.

The validation will be performed on an HTML text box. 
For any text provided I want to replace any and all occurrences of carriage return line feeds with a space.

**Is it possible to do this strictly in a regular expression? and if so, could you provide code samples?**

In this situation I can't do a JavaScript replace function or .NET replace function as the third party app does not allow for script functions.

Comment: If you have multiple consecutive CRLFs do they get replaced with as many spaces, or just one space?

Comment: `yourString.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ')` if we are talking about JS syntax; it should be the same regex for most other engines. This will replace any group of newline or carriage return characters with a single space. If you want to replace only CRLFs, then change the regex to `/(\r\n)+/`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Can't use a replace function. Will have to be strictly a regular expression.

Comment: Regex itself can only match, but can't modify. You need a replace.

Comment: Then there's no way to do this. The best you can do without a replace is to look for CRLFs, tell the user the input is invalid, and ask them to fix it themselves

Comment: What is your language? `re.sub` replaces, check out the Python documentation or google `python regex`. You could also `split` at all new lines and then `join` together with a space (look up `split` and `join` in Python string handling docs).